# Inegration test using maven

Tags: maven

I am trying to create something like integration tests - i am using groovy to send requests and to parse answers. I'd also want starting of jboss and deploying of .ear to be automatically. Using cargo plugin i was able to start jboss. By using exec plugin i am trying to execute perl script that puts ear to deploy folder. Next phase - execute groovy tests, but this phase starts without waiting for ear to be deployed. Is it possible to make  phase to wait for server to be deployed to jboss? My pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>unpack-application-server</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <source>${basedir}/src/main/script/appserver/unzip.groovy</source>
                   <defaults>
                      <installDirectory>${appserver.install.directory}</installDirectory>
                      <zipUrl>${appserver.zip.url}</zipUrl>
                   </defaults>
                </configuration>
             </execution>

             <execution>
                <id>prepare-application-server-configs</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <source>${basedir}/src/main/script/appserver/${suffix}/postUnzipAction.groovy</source>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
          <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>

          <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>start-container</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
             </execution>
          </executions>

          <configuration>
             <wait>false</wait>
             <container>
                <containerId>${appserver.id}</containerId>
                <home>${appserver.home}</home>
                <timeout>6000000</timeout> <!--in ms-->
             </container>

             <configuration>
                <properties>
                   <cargo.servlet.port>${servlet.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                   <cargo.rmi.port>${rmi.port}</cargo.rmi.port>
                   <!-- corresponds to -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 under jboss -->
                   <cargo.hostname>0.0.0.0</cargo.hostname>
                </properties>
             </configuration>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>

       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>deploy-with-script</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <executable>perl</executable>
                   <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                   <commandlineArgs>${deploy.pl.cmd} -x redeploy</commandlineArgs>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: You know you can use cargo to deploy your ear also?

Comment: @artbristol cargo is alread in use.

Comment: @khmarbaise I know that - it seems odd to use cargo to start the server, but not to deploy the ear

Answer (score 0):

1. setup and tear down your server before and after integration test phase, something like that:

   ```
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>start-tomcat</id>
           <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>run</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
       <execution>
           <id>stop-tomcat</id>
           <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>shutdown</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
   </executions>
   ```
2. Rename your unit tests to be skipped by surefire but executed by maven-failsave-plugin to *IT.java: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html